# TypeORM: Default values for primary column

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem when trying to save an entity to the DB with a primary column with a default value using TypeORM (in NestJs).

**TL;DR** How on earth do you set default column values with TypeORM when `default` just doesn't seem to do anything?

EDIT 1: Okay, so `default` seems to be DB level, kind of missed that before, but still `@BeforeInsert()` should do the trick then (yet doesn't).

EDIT 2: So apparently `@BeforeInsert()` hook works but only if `.save()` is called with `.save(new UserSession(userId))` and not with `.save({ userId: userId })` (which of course requires the appropriate constructor in `UserSession`).

### The setup

I have the entity `UserSession`, note the `sessionId` field, which is supposed to have a default value of whatever `cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: 'alphanumeric' })` returns.

```js
@Entity('user_session')
export class UserSession {
    
    @PrimaryColumn({ 
        name: 'session_id',
        default: () => cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: 'alphanumeric' })
    })
    sessionId: string
    
    @Column({ 
        name: 'user_id',
    })
    userId: string
   
}
```

I then use the TypeORM repository `.save()` function to write the object to the database like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserSession)
        private readonly userSessionRepository: Repository<UserSession>
    ) {}

    async createNewSession(userId: string): Promise<void> {
        // Create new session
        const session = await this.userSessionRepository.save({
            userId: userId
        })

       // If only it got that far...
    }
}
```

### The error

At this point I kind of expect TypeORM to set a default value for `sessionId` if nothing is set 'manually'. However, it just throws an error:

```
[Nest] 23088   - 04/06/2021, 23:18:44   [ExceptionsHandler] ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'session_id' doesn't have a default value +4032ms
QueryFailedError: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'session_id' doesn't have a default value
    at new QueryFailedError (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:12:28)
    at Query.<anonymous> (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\typeorm\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.js:217:45)
    at Query.<anonymous> (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (E:\SAC\projects\api-flexrent\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

### Despair

After spending some time on good old google I tried several variations, which all did not work (and throw the same error):

```js
@PrimaryColumn({ 
    name: 'session_id',
    default: cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: 'alphanumeric' })
})
sessionId: string
```

or

```js
@PrimaryColumn({ 
    name: 'session_id',
    default: () => 'cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: "alphanumeric" })' // Why would that even work
})
sessionId: string
```

or

```js
@PrimaryColumn({ 
    name: 'session_id',
    default: 'cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: "alphanumeric" })' // Why would that even work
})
sessionId: string
```

or

```js
@PrimaryColumn({ 
    name: 'session_id',
    default: 'please work'
})
sessionId: string
```

or not setting `default` in `@PrimaryColumn()` but rather using `@BeforeInsert()`, which apparently isn't called when using `.save()`

```js
@BeforeInsert()
beforeInsertAction(): void {
    this.sessionId = cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: 'alphanumeric' })
}
```

The only thing that did work was using a constructor for the `UserSession` class and setting the `sessionId` in there (which I thought kind of defeats the purpose of `default` values in TypeORM?):

```js
constructor(
    userId: string
) {
    this.userId = userId
    this.sessionId = cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: 'alphanumeric' })
}
```

and calling it with

```js
const session = await this.userSessionRepository.save(new UserSession(userId))
```

So, did I miss anything? Am I approaching the thing completely wrong, to begin with? I don't know anymore.

Comment: AFIK the value of `default` will be used at database level. For instance, `default: () => 'NULL'`. Use [`@BeforeInsert`](https://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers/beforeinsert) hook instead

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks for the quick answer, however calling `userSessionRepository.save({ userId: user.id })` with `@BeforeInsert()` in the `UserSession` class just doesn't seem to call the function that is annotated with `@BeforeInsert` (unlike described in the TypeORM docs). See the third last code snippet in my question.

Comment: well that's weird. I'm already using the hook aproach with `save` to define the PK value (just like you)

Comment: @MicaelLevi I think I found the problem, the hook only works if you call `.save()` with `new UserSession()`, not the way I called it (see my EDIT #2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to the problem that works...

I now defined my entity class like this:

```js
@Entity('user')
export class User {

  @PrimaryColumn({ 
    name: 'user_id',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 32
  })
  userId: string = cryptoRandomString({ length: 32, type: 'alphanumeric' })

  @Column({ 
    name: 'session_id',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 128
  })
  sessionId: string = cryptoRandomString({ length: 128, type: 'alphanumeric' })

  @Column({ 
    name: 'email',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 128
  })
  email: string

}
```

Now I can create my new user entity using repository's `.create()`:

```
const user: User = this.userRepo.create({ email: 'hello.world@example.com' })
```

Which creates the following object:

```
user: {
  userId: 'ivWW8oMGD8oMh2FL0vM3Grrh2FL0M3Di'
  sessionId: 'vM3DiW8oMGrh2FL0vM3DiW8oMGrh2FL0vM3DiW8oMGrh2FL0vM3DiW8oMGrh2FL0...'
  email: 'hello.world@example.com'
}
```

Which can then again be saved using the `.save()` method:

```js
await this.userRepo.save(user)
```

Comment: nice, just setting the value initially, which can be overwritten later? is there a better way to do this in 2024?